# Fuse box location for 2006 Renault Scenic

Tags: fuse, renault, scenic

I've have a 2006 Renault Scenic 1.6 Liter.  I can't seem to find where the fuse box is located as it's not where it says it is in the handbook. The cigarette lighter fuse has blown but cant find the fuse box to change it.

**Please can you help you help me to locate fuse box?**

Comment: Where does the manual tell you the fuse box should be? There may be a cover or drawer you have to pull out to access it.

Answer (score 5):

I found manual [here](http://www.manuals365.com/download/renault/renault_scenic_owners_manual_2006.html).

The fuse box information is on pages 5.18 and 5.19, if you download the PDF:
[image]
[image]

So it looks like it depends on whether your Scenic is a UK? model (steering wheel on the right) or a rest-of-Europe? model (steering wheel on the left).

- For right-side steering wheel, the fuse box is in the left-hand side of the glove compartment.
- For left-side steering wheel, the fuse box is to the left of the steering column, underneath some controls.

Do either of these match the model of Scenic you have?